# Which option needs to be set to create a home directory for a new user using "useradd" command?

Tags: command-line, useradd

My answers:
useradd -d
useradd -m
useradd -m -d username
useradd -d -m username
sudo useradd -d username
and i think i put all the letters from "man useradd"...stil non of the answers there are not good
spending hours and i don't find nowhere any clue

Answer (score 3):

If you’re doing this via the command line, you just need `-m`:

```
sudo useradd -m {username}
```

If there is no `-m`, no home directory will be created. In the event you want to specify a path for the home directory, use `-d` and specify a directory:

```
sudo useradd -m -d /your/preferred/path {username}
```

From there you can set the account password with:

```
sudo passwd {username}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this issue for HTB management resource you just need to specify the option , so just put it which will be  `-m`

Comment: I'm not sure what an "HTB management resource" is - does it affect how `-m` should be used?

Answer (score 0):

you can see here all the things you want to do, and also the different between adduser vs useradd, https://linuxconfig.org/add-user-linux-command
at the end you can see the:

exemple2 - If you want the useradd command to create a new home directory for your user, you will need to append the **-m** option.